# How to display a video file without using the video hosting websides?

Tags: 7, theming, files

I need to display video file without using youtube, vimeo etc.
I am using the bootstrap theme. I've tried to using some modules with no luck:

1. Module: MediaFront,
    Field type: File,
    Display mode: MediaFront Player

   File is not rendering at all.
2. Module: Video, 
   Field type: Video 
   On Chrome looks fine, but there is a
   problem on Safari (can't debug it – tested on iPad).

I'm looking for some module/way that enables me to embed a responsive video.

Answer (score 0):

The Media project (https://www.drupal.org/project/media) has support for displaying uploaded video files using native HTML5.